# В каких случаях работает процентная высота с flexbox'ом?

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Обнаружил интересную особенность флексбокса: в большинстве браузеров можно не указывать высоту у элементов в горизонтальном флексбоксе. В следующем примере у `section` высота не задана, но `div` растягивается вертикально на всю высоту в IE11, Edge, Chrome и FF. Хотя это и не работает в iOS 9 Safari.

https://jsfiddle.net/qy6thr1s/

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

section:first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: silver;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<section><div>123</div></section>
<section>456</section>
```

Однако, если сделать флекс вертикальным, то работать перестаёт - и это известный факт, который "чинится" абсолютным позиционированием.

https://jsfiddle.net/qy6thr1s/1/

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section:first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: silver;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<section><div>123</div></section>
<section>456</section>
```

Интересно, что первый вариант с добавленным `flex-wrap` продолжает работать:

https://jsfiddle.net/qy6thr1s/2/

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section:first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: silver;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  background: antiquewhite;
}

section:last-of-type {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<section><div>123</div></section>
<section>456</section>
<section>890</section>
```

**Так в каких же случаях можно не прописывать высоту и насколько это кроссбраузерно?**

Answer (score 2):

NB. Ответ не претендует на академическую точность.

Переключая `flex-direction` между `column` и `row` мы переключаем главную ось, соответственно, внимание к контенту также переключается с `width` на `height`. Сразу приведу пример:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

section:first-child div {
  background-color: red;
}

div {
  width: 100%; /* явно зададим ширину для иллюстрации */
  height: 100%; /* и высоту тоже */
}
```

```html
<section><div>123</div></section>
<section>456</section>
```

Здесь ширина, имеющая значение `100%` никак не применяется.

Теперь просто поменяем `flex-direction`:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

section:first-child div {
  background-color: red;
}

div {
  width: 100%; /* явно зададим ширину для иллюстрации */
  height: 100%; /* и высоту тоже */
}
```

```html
<section><div>123</div></section>
<section>456</section>
```

Теперь можно увидеть обратный результат: 100%-ная ширина контента применилась, а 100%-ная высота — нет.

Однако, так мы меняем только поведение флексбокса, поведение самого дива не меняется — он все еще следует правилам блочного контекста форматирования, а именно занимает все доступное место по ширине и минимальное по высоте.

---

Теперь постараюсь ответить на сам вопрос. При смене главной оси с X на Y, у флексбокса теряется привязка к определенной в его свойствах высоте, а значит внутреннему диву не на что сослаться, если задать ему `height: 100%`. Решить это можно при помощи определения высоты у непосредственного потомка при помощи `flex-basis` или `height`.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  /* height: 50%; */
}

section:first-child div {
  background-color: red;
}

div {
  width: 100%; /* явно зададим ширину для иллюстрации */
  height: 100%; /* и высоту тоже */
}
```

```html
<section><div>123</div></section>
<section>456</section>
```

---

Свойство-значение `flex-wrap: wrap` никак не влияет на расчет размеров, поскольку не меняется главная ось.

---

Источники:

> https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/

Comment: Посмотри на третий пример - в нём 100% сработает совсем не так, как работает при неуказанном.

Comment: да, и это естественно, что тут не так? `flex-wrap` переносит элементы, они начинают занимать пропорциональную высоту от 100% (в данном случае по 50%). див с заданными 100% высоты занимает всю доступную высоту как и прежде.

Comment: @Qwertiy так всё же, это отвечает на твой вопрос?

Comment: Эм.. Хотелось бы конкретно и прям со ссылками на места спецификации...